# iOS Enterprise OTA starts but results in "Waiting..." under icon

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, ota

I have followed all of the instructions and when installing from a web page link I get the install propmt on my iPhone but then the app icon shows up and the "Waiting..." status shows under the icon. No progress is made on the progress bar -- it just stalls. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give the webpage link which you have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for bad files as Owen mentioned. Also check the file permissions of the ipa and supporting plist on the server where you are hosting them.
I had this file permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a bad file, either the ipa file or the supporting plist.  Check your build process for any errors.  Make sure you have all the right files in the download package.